# ERROR 1044 creating a trigger in mysql on pythonanywhere

Tags: mysql, mysql-python, pythonanywhere

I have created a database in pythonanywhere, after doing my migrations from my django project etc.. i wanted to create a trigger in my db, but the following message appears:

> ERROR 1419 (HY000): You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

My user does not have the permissions

Comment: If you don't have the admin privilege to set the `log_bin_trust_function_creators` variable, then you can't create this trigger. Find another solution to do what you were going to do without using a trigger.

Comment: is there another way to get de admin privilege?, due that I am the admin?

Comment: ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE U
SER privilege(s) for this operation another message thata apperas when a user is being created

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create triggers in MySQL on PythonAnywhere